# How to update a table if a row is deleted in another one

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I have a table that contains products... something like

```
productname | price | category .... .... ...
```

category contains an INT value and it is the ID of the choosen category

```
id | categoryname | categorydescription ... ...
```

When I delete a Category (because this is a Ecommerce site I'm making in PHP, so the user can manage and delete categories at will), I want all the products whose Category is the Deleted Category ID, to set that value to 0, in other words, no category set.

I want to know how to do this with only MYSQL, and let me know if I should do it through PHP code.

Comment: I suppose you can do that with trigger. Make trigger fire on delete event.

Comment: I've research and I haven't understood the examples I see around the web, I can't figure out how can I apply them to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can do with triggers. It's untested. It's from my archive. Please check.

```
CREATE TRIGGER del_cat_prod AFTER DELETE on category
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update products set category_id  = 0 where category_id  = old.id;        
END
```

Comment: Where does the "old.id" come from? It knows that old.id means "deletedrow.categoryid" ? something like that?

Comment: old.id is recently deleted id from category table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
UPDATE products SET category = 0 WHERE category = 'ur id' ;
```

Comment: I know I know, but... how to make MYSQL do it automatically when a row is deleted from the categories table? without PHP

Comment: You may want to look into using a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) @JuanBonnett

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Triggers .

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html